# String tokenizer does not properly handle null tokens or multiple delimiters in a row

Tags: javascript, tokenize, strtok

So I have a simple strtok implementation in javascript. For some reason if you try to pass it multiple delimiters in a row inside your string it parses every other delimiter as a character. For example `"This,, and that"` delimted by `","` and `" "` will return and array of [`This`, `,`, `and`, `that`]. The second comma, because it immediately follows another delimiter gets seen as a non-delimiter caharacter.

here's the code:

```
//@param str: a string to tokenize
//@param tok: an array of chars to be delimiters
//@return: an array of strings.

var strtok = function(str, tok)
{
    if(str === "") return [];

    var ret = [],
    _buffer = str,
    sub,
    b = _buffer.charAt(0),
    start = 0,
    i = 0,
    len = _buffer.length; 

    while(i <= len) {
        b = _buffer.charAt(i);
        tok.forEach(function(elm) {
            if (b === elm) {              
                sub = _buffer.slice(start, i);
                if(!(sub in tok)) ret.push(sub);
                start = ++i;
                return;
            } 
        });  
        i++;
    }
    ret.push(_buffer.slice(start, len));
    return ret;
}

var str = "This,, that";
var tok = '. ,'.split('');
console.log(strtok(str,tok));
// ["This", ",", "that"]
str = "This,,, that";
console.log(strtok(str, tok));
// ["This", ",", " that"] <- notice the space before that
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index gets overincremented, line to blame is `start = ++i;`, fix would be `start = i + 1;`.